# Why does event bubbling does not occur when events are attached using addeventListener

Tags: javascript

In the following code, click event is attached using `addEventListener` to every `p` element. Since the `click` event is attached to every parent or nested `p` element, I expected that clicking on child `p` would also trigger attached click event of parent `p` due to event bubbling. However that does not happen.

Does attaching event using `addEventListener`, that event does not bubble up (propagate up) by default?

```js
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (idx = 0; idx < content.length; idx++) {
  content[idx].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.parentNode.classList)
  }, false)
}
```

```css
.ancestor p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent>p {
  background-color: blue
}

.child p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="ancestor">
    <p>Ancestor Pargraph</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>Parent Paragraph</p>
      <div class="child" tabindex='2'>
        <p>Child Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: _`useCapture` - a Boolean indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events that are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture... If not specified, useCapture defaults to false._ [ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: The <p> are not parents of anything. every click to a `<p>` just bubbles to a parent div (which has no listener, then it bubbles to another div (with no listener) and bypasses that div's child which is a `<p>`, and so on. Bubbling proceeds to the next ancestor not ancestor's children.

Comment: @hindmost Capture is the third parameter defaulted to false (as it is explicitly set in OPs code). So that doesn't apply hence bubbling does work just not in the way everyone expected apparently.

Answer (score 0):

## Event Bubbling Triggers Ancestors Not the Children of Ancestors

The `<p>` are not parents of anything. every click to a `<p>` just bubbles to a parent div (which has no listener, then it bubbles to another div (with no listener) and bypasses that div's child which is a `<p>`, and so on. Bubbling proceeds to the next ancestor not ancestor's children.

In the following demo each `<div>` has an `eventListener()`. Each `<div>` is a parent (unlike the `<p>`) and you'll see that event bubbling works.

---

### Demo

```js
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (idx = 0; idx < content.length; idx++) {
  content[idx].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.classList)
  }, false)
}
```

```css
.ancestor p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent>p {
  background-color: blue
}

.child p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="ancestor">
    <p>Ancestor Pargraph</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>Parent Paragraph</p>
      <div class="child" tabindex='2'>
        <p>Child Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```